# Keep getting error function was never awaited asyncio for python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can't figure this out at all, I looked all the questions, videos, and documents. So I keep getting back was never awaited for `async def renk_calc() -> bool:` So I'm trying to get this function to preform its calculation and to return. I can't get it to work, no matter what method I tried, I ran into a different problem.

From reading trying to understand I have to run this function on separate thread or a separate processor, but I kept getting errors back its not coroutine is not callable, and coroutine is none, and coroutine cannot be a pickle. It's probably because I'm very new to asyncio, and I was reading the documentation to implement a solution.

but in essence this function gets input from `async def renko_append():` as this appends the dictionary then that feeds the DataFrame, and I know the DataFrame is causing the issue because it's not a awaitable object or curatable object. But I don't know how to fix it.

then the dictionary gets cleared. So it loops back and refills it again and that's the marry go round. The idea is then to grab the returned value in the function and utilize it in the next block.

```
nest_asyncio.apply()

list = []

renk = {"DATE":[],"OPEN":[],"HIGH":[],"LOW":[],"CLOSE":[]}

async def renko_append():
      
      current_time = datetime.now()
      global list
     

      # print(f"this is the {list}")
      
      renk["DATE"].append(current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      renk["OPEN"].append(list[0])
      renk["HIGH"].append(max(list))
      renk["LOW"].append(min(list))
      renk["CLOSE"].append(list[-1])
      print(renk)
      list.clear()

      
async def renk_calc() -> bool:

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(renk)
        df.columns = [i.lower() for i in df.columns]
        renko_ind = indicators.Renko(df)
        renko_ind.brick_size = 0.0006
        
        renko_ind.chart_type = indicators.Renko.PERIOD_CLOSE
        data = renko_ind.get_ohlc_data()
        result = data["uptrend"]
        return result


async def clr_dict():
    renk["DATE"] = []
    renk["OPEN"] = []
    renk["HIGH"] = []
    renk["LOW"] =  []
    renk["CLOSE"] =[]
    
    print(renk)




async def main():
    
    async def deal_msg(msg):
          
        if msg['topic'] == '/contractMarket/ticker:ADAUSDTM':
            ns = msg["data"]["ts"]
            time = datetime.fromtimestamp(ns // 1000000000)
            my_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            price = msg["data"]["price"]
            # print(f'Get ADAUSDTM Ticker:price: {price} side: {msg["data"]["side"]} time: {my_time}')
            list.append(price)


    # client = WsToken()

    client = WsToken(key='', secret='', passphrase='', is_sandbox=False, url='')
    

    ws_client = await KucoinFuturesWsClient.create(loop, client, deal_msg, private=False)
    await ws_client.subscribe('/contractMarket/ticker:ADAUSDTM')
    
    
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10, loop=loop)
        
        await asyncio.create_task(renko_append())
        await asyncio.create_task(renk_calc())
        await asyncio.create_task(clr_dict())
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I edited to add the error: I figured out the "await" problem, but now I'm stuck on this error.

`TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable`

`async def renk_calc()` this is whats not callable

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Remove the line `print(f"{renk_calc()}")`, your function `renk_calc()` is a coroutine function, you should always await it. And make sure that the 3rd parameter of the `KucoinFuturesWsClient.create` function needs a coroutine object but not a function pointer.

Comment: also do `await asyncio.create_task(renk_calc)`